# Getting information from SpooledTemporaryFile that is a zip

Tags: python, fastapi

I am uploading a zip file with Fast API and it takes in the files as a SpooledTemporaryFile. I have been trying to copy that file onto disk. I have attempted various things; the two I feel I have made progress in are down below.

1. I have attempted to use zipfile.Zipfile, when I turn it into one I am unable to unzip it because it says it is not a zip.
2. I also uploaded a single file that is not zipped and turned the SpooledTemporaryFile into _io.BytesIO, however, when I try to read the content of a single file (not zipped) it returned empty byte (b'').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@app.post("/", status_code=200)
async def upload(file: bytes = File(...)):
 zip_file_name = "file.zip"
    
 with open(zip_file_name, 'wb') as zip_file:
  zip_file.write(file)
```

I switched from accepting a `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` to a bytes as suggested by [C H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5842425/c-h) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63016816/9578009).

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually working on something similar and ran into the same issues. The solution I came up with was to use [the `File` option (not the `UploadFile` one)](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#define-file-parameters), write the input to another file, then perform the unzip.

Here's my implementation using a TemporaryDirectory and separate directories for input and unzipped files:

```
@router.post("/test_file/unzip")
def unzip_upload(file: bytes = File(...)):

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        os.chdir(temp_dir)
        os.mkdir('input')
        os.mkdir('unzipped')

        with open("input/zip_file.zip", 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(file)
            # print(f"output of listdir for /input {os.listdir(temp_dir + '/input')}")

            with zipfile.ZipFile("input/zip_file.zip") as zip_file:
                print(f"files in zip: {zip_file.namelist()}")
                zip_file.extractall('unzipped')

        unzipped_files = os.listdir('unzipped')

    return {"unzipped files": unzipped_files}
```

If you need to use the `UploadFile` option, I got this to work:

```
@router.post("/test_uploadfile/unzip")
def unzip_upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        os.chdir(temp_dir)
        os.mkdir('input')
        os.mkdir('unzipped')

        with open("input/zip_file.zip", 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(file.file._file.getvalue())
            # print(f"output of listdir for /input {os.listdir(temp_dir + '/input')}")

            with zipfile.ZipFile("input/zip_file.zip") as zip_file:
                print(f"files in zip: {zip_file.namelist()}")
                zip_file.extractall('unzipped')

        unzipped_files = os.listdir('unzipped')

    return {"unzipped files": unzipped_files}
```

Comment: Thank you, although this method did not work for me; it did lead me to the correct. I was getting error with the file was not a zip file.